# Update cart shipping data with AJAX in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce, checkout

I'm trying to update my checkout cart's shipping with AJAX...

I've got the action in functions.php

```
function jwd_update_shipping()
{
    WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();

    echo "hi";
    die();
}
add_action('jwd_update_shipping_callback', 'jwd_update_shipping');
```

Then in js I call it, like so

```js
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'MYSITE.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: ({
        action: "jwd_update_shipping"
    }),
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("got this: " + response);
        if (response.type == "success") {
            alert("here");
            jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
        } else {
            alert("fail");
        }
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

I just get a 0 alerted back at me, which suggests that the AJAX call failed.

Comment: put an echo before calculate shipping is it actually getting in jwd_update_shipping .. also try parenthesis () for the action data in ajax

Comment: Your add_action() is wrong. Please read the documentation - https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 0):

First your ajax request is not reaching the related php function… Also you need more things to refresh checkout… Try the following instead:

```
// The jQuery script that send the Ajax request
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'refresh_shipping_js' );
function refresh_shipping_js() {
    // Only on checkout
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ):
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        if (typeof wc_checkout_params === 'undefined') 
            return false;

        var refresh = 'yes';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
            data: ({
                'action': 'updating_shipping',
                'refresh_shipping': refresh,

            }),
            success: function(response) {
                if( response === '1' ) {
                    $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
                    console.log('Success: '+response); // For testing (to be removed)
                } else {
                    console.log('Failled: '+response); // For testing (to be removed)
                }
            },
            error:function(error) {
                console.log('Error: '+error); // For testing (to be removed)
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// function that gets the Ajax data
add_action( 'wp_ajax_updating_shipping', 'updating_shipping' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_updating_shipping', 'updating_shipping' );
function updating_shipping() {
    if ( isset($_POST['refresh_shipping']) && $_POST['refresh_shipping'] === 'yes' ){
        WC()->session->set('refresh_shipping', '1' );
    } else {
        WC()->session->set('refresh_shipping', '0' );
    }
    echo  WC()->session->get('refresh_shipping');
    die(); // Alway at the end (to avoid server error 500)
}

// Function that refresh session shipping methods data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'refresh_shipping_methods', 10, 1 );
function refresh_shipping_methods( $post_data ){
    if ( WC()->session->get('refresh_shipping' ) === '1' ) {
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages() as $package_key => $package ){
            WC()->session->set( 'shipping_for_package_' . $package_key, false );
        }
        WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
    }
}
```